# C++ VTK initialize volume using pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vtk

I have a volume of size `NX x NY x NZ x NC`, where `NC = 3` is the number of channels, i.e., the colors of the voxels.

The volume should be visualized using VTK in C++. However, I don't know how to initialize the volume in VTK if the data is already stored in memory without performing a deep copy using a 4D nested loop.

The following code should be considered as pseudocode to get an idea of the desired outcome.

```cpp
unsigned int NX = 100, NY = 100, NZ = 100, NC = 3;
float *volPtr = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * NX * NY * NZ * NC); // pointer to raw data

vtkNew<vtkVolume> vol;  // or vtkNew<vtkStructuredGrid> vol;

// vol.setPointer(volPtr); // <- I need to find a way to do this

// EDIT: This makes arr point to volPtr without copying it.
//       Maybe the vtkFloatArray can be converted to a volume.
vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> arr;
arr->SetArray(volPtr, NX * NY * NZ * NC, 1);

while (true) {
    generate_data(volPtr); // dummy function to generate new data and write it to vol

    // The VTK object 'vol' should now contain the new data as it points to volPtr

    // Visualize the volume
    // ...
}
```

Comment: For future ref, similar question [here](https://discourse.vtk.org/t/visualize-complex-valued-3d-volume/6982)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [`vtkImageData`](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html) with dimensions of `[NX+1, NY+1, NY+1]` (it is the number of points in each direction, so 1 more than voxels)

Then create your float array. Specify

```
arr->SetNumberOfComponents(3)
```

because each voxel is a tuple of 3 values. Also specify a name.

Next, add it to your image data as a `CellData`:

```
image->GetCellData()->AddArray(arr)
```

Finally you can visualize your image, for instance with [volume rendering](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Cxx/VolumeRendering/SmartVolumeMapper/).

### Edit

#### about VTK data structure

In VTK, data are quite always attached to a mesh. A mesh is a list of points, linked by cells. The `vtkImageData` is a structured, regular grid so points and cells are implicit: you just need to give dimensions to create it. Points are mathematical points defined by coords. Voxels are ... voxels: cubes defined by 8 points.

An array of data, as `vtkFloatData` is the way to associates a value to each point or cell. In your case, you have 3 components (R, G and B) for each voxel so in memory you should have `R0 G0 B0 R1 G1 B1 ... Rn Gn Bn`.

#### magnitude

If you want the magnitude at each voxel you should compute it (and add it in another `vtkFloatArray`).

Comment: Why do I have to use a `vtkImageData` instance of size `[NX+1, NY+1, NZ+1]`? Where is the difference between points and voxels? Also, with an array with three components, I assume that each element should contain the corresponding x, y, and z component. But what about the additional element? And how do I specify the magnitude then?

Comment: Well, most is VTK data structure understanding. For magnitude, it is just another data to compute and add. I have updated my answer for that